# LOG4j 2.17 did not accept log4j2.properties and only accept properties file in log4j1.2 syntax

Tags: apache-spark, log4j2

I'm running a scala program with log4j 2.17 and I've remove all log4j 1.2 dependencies from sbt file. According to the sbt dependencyTree, the program did not depend on log4j1.2 and log4j-1.2-api-2.x.jar.
But it only accept properies file in log4j1.+ syntax.

I dont know what the problem should be. Is the program still using log4j 1.2? How can I make it use log4j2.+ properties file?

When I use log4j2 syntax. Log4j report such error

```
log4j: Using URL [file:/etc/spark/conf/log4j2.properties] for automatic log4j configuration.
log4j: Reading configuration from URL file:/etc/spark/conf/log4j2.properties
log4j: Could not find root logger information. Is this OK?
log4j: Finished configuring.
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

The log4j2.properties file:

```
#
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
#

# Set everything to be logged to the console
rootLogger.level = info
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = console

# In the pattern layout configuration below, we specify an explicit `%ex` conversion
# pattern for logging Throwables. If this was omitted, then (by default) Log4J would
# implicitly add an `%xEx` conversion pattern which logs stacktraces with additional
# class packaging information. That extra information can sometimes add a substantial
# performance overhead, so we disable it in our default logging config.
# For more information, see SPARK-39361.
appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = console
appender.console.target = SYSTEM_ERR
appender.console.layout.type = JsonTemplateLayout
appender.console.layout.eventTemplate = { "JobId":"123" }

# Set the default spark-shell/spark-sql log level to WARN. When running the
# spark-shell/spark-sql, the log level for these classes is used to overwrite
# the root logger's log level, so that the user can have different defaults
# for the shell and regular Spark apps.
logger.repl.name = org.apache.spark.repl.Main
logger.repl.level = warn

logger.thriftserver.name = org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkSQLCLIDriver
logger.thriftserver.level = warn

# Settings to quiet third party logs that are too verbose
logger.jetty1.name = org.sparkproject.jetty
logger.jetty1.level = warn
logger.jetty2.name = org.sparkproject.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle
logger.jetty2.level = error
logger.replexprTyper.name = org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$exprTyper
logger.replexprTyper.level = info
logger.replSparkILoopInterpreter.name = org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$SparkILoopInterpreter
logger.replSparkILoopInterpreter.level = info
logger.parquet1.name = org.apache.parquet
logger.parquet1.level = error
logger.parquet2.name = parquet
logger.parquet2.level = error

# SPARK-9183: Settings to avoid annoying messages when looking up nonexistent UDFs in SparkSQL with Hive support
logger.RetryingHMSHandler.name = org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler
logger.RetryingHMSHandler.level = fatal
logger.FunctionRegistry.name = org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionRegistry
logger.FunctionRegistry.level = error

# For deploying Spark ThriftServer
# SPARK-34128: Suppress undesirable TTransportException warnings involved in THRIFT-4805
appender.console.filter.1.type = RegexFilter
appender.console.filter.1.regex = .*Thrift error occurred during processing of message.*
appender.console.filter.1.onMatch = deny
appender.console.filter.1.onMismatch = neutral
```

Log4j properties in 1.2+ syntax

```
# Set everything to be logged to the console
# root
log4j.rootLogger=INFO,console
# appender encoding
log4j.appender.logFile.Encoding = UTF-8
# console
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.target=System.error
log4j.appender.console.Threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.console.encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern={"JobId":"123"}%n
```

Comment: Warnings prefixed by `log4j:` are only published by Log4j 1.2 or its fork Reload4j.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz Does it mean I'm actually logging with log4j 1.2, despide somehow I'm not able to find log4j 1.2 in the dependency tree？

Comment: you either have Log4j 1.2 or its fork Reload4j.